# Average Effectiveness of Variables in Binary Logistic Model

Tags: average, regression, effect, spss, coefficients

I have constructed a binary logistic model to check the effect of various variables on the probability of a consumer to buy. I have 5 different brands, and in the model I have 5 price variables which are specific to the brand (interaction between brand dummy and price). So my output looks like this:

```
                         Coefficient               P-value
Price_Brand_A                0.25                    0.02
Price_Brand_B                0.50                    0.01
Price_Brand_C                0.10                    0.09
Price_Brand_D                0.40                    0.15
Price_Brand_E                0.65                    0.02
```

What I would like to ask, is if it is correct to say something about the overall effect of price, and not specifically about the brands. For instance would it be correct to take the average of the coefficients and say that the average effect of price is equal to 0.38? Or is there some statistical procedure I should follow to report the overall effect of price? Also would the same apply for the P-value?

I am working with spss and I am new at modelling so any help would be appreciated.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you test an interaction hypothesis, you have to include a number of terms in your model. In this case, you would have to include:

- Base effect of price
- Base effects of brands (dummies)
- Interaction effects of brand dummies * price.

Since you have 5 brands, you will have to include 4 of the 5 dummy variables. The dummy you leave out will be your reference category. The same goes for the interaction terms. In this case, the base effect of price will be the effect of price for the reference category of brands. The base of dummies will be the difference between brands if the price would be 0. The interaction effects can be interpreted in two different ways. On way is to say that the effect of an interaction term would be the additional price effect of one brand, compared to the reference category of brands. The other way is to say that the interaction effect is the additional difference between the brand and the reference brand if price increases by one.

If you want to know what the average effect of price is, why would you include interaction terms? In that case, I would leave out the interactions in a first model, and then include the interactions to show that the average effect of price is not accurate if you would look at the effect for each brand.

Maybe you could post some more output? I think you got more out of it than you posted in your question?

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer Matt! It indeed gives me some clarification. 
In my case I have also tried to run the model without the price interactions and just including one variable of price, but then it proves to be insignificant. But when I run it with the brand specific prices they are significant (because apart from price, they work a bit like brand constants which explain differences between brands I guess). In any case, the matter is that I would like to know if it makes sense to calculate the average of the coefficients and report it as the "average" effect of price.

Comment: Also coming back to your comment about the dummies, then if I were to run the regression without the model constant, would I be able to include all 5 dummies? And then maybe calculate the "average" effect

Comment: No, calculating the average of the coefficients does not result in the average effect of price. Don't do it! The average effect of price is the one you mentioned that was insignificant. This means that, on average, price has no significant effect on the odds of buying a product. Did you control for brands in that model?
However, there is an effect of price for certain groups in your data, which you uncovered by including interaction effects.
If you really want to include the interactions and unravel the average effect, you could look into 'effects coding' for dummies.

Comment: And to answer your last question: you cannot include all dummies. You need to leave one out. Otherwise, the model cannot be estimated. Can you post all of your output? That would make it easier to comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will take a deeper look into "effects coding" then, seems quite interesting! Unfortunately I cannot post any output because it is confidential to the university, but rest assured you 've provided substantial help. 
Cheers!